# AdonisJS Lucid - Error: Package subpath './package.json' is not defined by "exports" in \package.json

Tags: node.js, typescript, adonisjs-ace

I'm discovering AdonisJS after a long time using ExpressJS and i would like to connect my db using Lucid ORM. I followed the basic instructions from doc to install and configure but i have this error that i dont understand and can't resolve.

```
Error: Package subpath './package.json' is not defined by "exports" in
   C:\Users\David\Music\Lab\Sites\BackEnd\tableau-periodique-adonis\node_modules\@adonisjs\lucid\package.json

   ⁃ resolveFileName
     C:/Users/David/Music/Lab/Sites/BackEnd/tab-periodic/node_modules/resolve-from/index.js:29
   ⁃ resolveFrom
     C:/Users/David/Music/Lab/Sites/BackEnd/tab-periodic-adonis/node_modules/resolve-from/index.js:43
   ⁃ module.exports
     C:/Users/David/Lab/Sites/BackEnd/tab-periodic-adonis/node_modules/resolve-from/index.js:46
```

Create the project with `npm init adonis-ts-app@latest tab-periodic-adonis`

Then i try to install lucid using `npm i @adonisjs/lucid` then `node ace configure @adonisjs/lucid`
but i gives me this error :

```
Error: Package subpath './package.json' is not defined by "exports" in
   C:\Users\David\Music\Lab\Sites\BackEnd\tableau-periodique-adonis\node_modules\@adonisjs\lucid\package.json
```

Can someone explain me where is the problem please ? I've tried some solutions from this forum but nothing solved it

Node version : 21.6.0 and npm version 10.2.4